# Storing images in isolated storage in background

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing app in which i have check first the images is present in isolated storage.If image is not there then i download first and then store them in isolated storage .But I got exception "An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code " at   `using (IsolatedStorageFileStream mystream = istore.CreateFile(item.ImageUrl)).`

```
  private void checkimage(Model item)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile istore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            if (istore.FileExists(item.ImageUrl))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                BitmapImage imgage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.ImageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
                imgage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
                imgage.ImageOpened += (o, e) =>
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream mystream = istore.CreateFile(item.ImageUrl))
                        {
                            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                            bitmap.SetSource(mystream);
                            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

                            Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, mystream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                            mystream.Close();
                        }

                    };
               }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like istore has been destroyed at the time, when you trying to create the file. Try to create (istore) again in the event body or use global variable and handle dispose by hand.

For example: move `BitmapImage imgage...` outside the first `using` and create istore again.

Comment: Thanks . It was same problem as you suggest

Comment: It is Because the name of the file that i can store in the isolated storage is very large.